# PowerPoint.Application not raising events in C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a simple application written in C# and .Net 2.0 that displays several PowerPoint 2003 files in a loop. (It is going to be used for a information board in our cafeteria)  The application works fine on my development machine but when I deploy it to another machine the events I have registered for SlideShowNextSlide and PresentationClose are never fired. I have tried registering the events with this method.

```
private void InitPPT()
    {
        app.SlideShowNextSlide += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_SlideShowNextSlideEventHandler(app_SlideShowNextSlide);
        app.PresentationClose += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_PresentationCloseEventHandler(app_PresentationClose);
        app.SlideShowEnd += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_SlideShowEndEventHandler(app_PresentationClose);
    }
```

And with this method that I found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308825):

```
private void InitPPT()
    {
        IConnectionPointContainer oConnPointContainer = (IConnectionPointContainer)app;
        Guid guid = typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication).GUID;
        oConnPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref guid, out m_oConnectionPoint);
        m_oConnectionPoint.Advise(this, out m_Cookie);            
    }
```

Do I need to register some dll's on the client machine or am I missing something.

Comment: I have checked the client machine and Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint is registered in the GAC.

Comment: I think I may have found part of the problem which presents a new question.  My app is impersonating a different user account so it has access to the network.  If my app and PowerPoint aren't running under the same account I assume it would not be able to receive events from PowerPoint.  The question is then how to get PowerPoint running under the same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was due to the fact that I was trying to run my application from a local user account but impersonate a domain account so I could access network drives.  I have changed my application so it only impersonates the domain account while preforming network operations and not at application startup.